# "comparison across the two classrooms" vs. "comparison between classroom A and classroom B"

Tags: differences

My question is about differences between the following:

> 1. comparison across the two classrooms
> 2. comparison between classroom A and classroom B

Would you answer my question?

Comment: It may prove helpful to clarify what form you'd like answers to take or what specifically you are wondering about the difference.

Answer (score 2):

There is little difference in meaning between the example phrases.  However, I'm inclined to reserve  *comparison across* for cases where more than two things are being compared.  *Between* is used fairly specifically when two things are referred to, and *among* for more ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/69921/is-between-always-used-for-two-things),[2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10326/third-alternative-to-between-and-among),[3](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/79390/find-a-new-job-between-the-posted-jobs-or-find-a-new-job-among-the-posted-job),[4](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/45445/theres-something-wrong-among-us-or-theres-something-wrong-between-us),[5](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/85370/between-and-among-alternate-among),[6](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/64623/how-does-among-vs-between-affect-the-meaning-of-this-sentence-from-the-times),[7](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/52276/difference-between-multiple-choices-vs-among),[8](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/what-is-the-distinction-between-among-and-amongst),[9](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37636/between-vs-among)).  *[Across](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/across#Preposition)*, in its sense of spanning, suggests more than two items.